# Scroll Bar on Form Scrolls to Wrong Row on Spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

System:  MS Office Pro Plus 2010 on Win7 Home Premium

OK, This is annoying!  Should be so simple.

I have a vertical scrollbar on a form. The scrollbar scrolls the spreadsheet beneath the form while the form remains open.  Some of the rows on the spreadsheet are hidden and need to remain hidden.  Often, when I click the small-change arrow on the scroll bar UP, it will actually move the form DOWN. The small change value is 1.

What I Tried: I have added code so that if the target row is a hidden row, I continue to subtract until I get to a visible row. This did not solve the problem.

I also tried creating a blank excel with 1 button and a form with nothing but a scrollbar and simplified version of the code below. Got the same problem.

P.S. I have the exact same problem when using the DOWN (small change) ARROW.

```
' This is in the form Initialize routine
    With Me.sbRows
     .Min = 1
     .Max = lFindNewRow(m_wksPST)
     .Value = ActiveWindow.ScrollRow
     .LargeChange = 25
     .SmallChange = 1
    End With

' This is the vertical scrollbar change routine
Private Sub sbRows_Change()
    ' If target row is hidden, keep looking until we find a visible row to use as the target.
   Dim lDiff As Long

   With Me.sbRows
      lDiff = .Value - mlPrevScrollRow  ' Stores the top row before scrollbar was clicked
      Debug.Print "Prev " & mlPrevScrollRow & " New " & .Value & " diff " & lDiff
      mlPrevScrollRow = .Value
      While m_wksPST.Rows(mlPrevScrollRow).Hidden And mlPrevScrollRow > 0 And _
            mlPrevScrollRow < 65500
        If lDiff < 0 Then
            mlPrevScrollRow = mlPrevScrollRow - 1
        Else
            mlPrevScrollRow = mlPrevScrollRow + 1
        End If
      Wend
    End With
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = mlPrevScrollRow
    Debug.Print "Move to " & mlPrevScrollRow
End Sub
```

*** Example of output when only clicking UP (Small Change) ARROW  ***

Prev 884 New 883 diff -1  ' Good. Scroll up 1 to a hidden row, look for visible row above.

Move to 880               ' Good.

Prev 880 New 882 diff 2   ' Bad. Where did it get 882 instead of 879?

Move to 884

Prev 884 New 881 diff -3  ' Bad. Why -3 not -1? Why is new 881 not 883?

Move to 880

Prev 880 New 880 diff 0

Move to 880

Prev 880 New 879 diff -1

Move to 876

Prev 876 New 878 diff 2

Move to 880

*** Visible rows in this range ****
874
876
880
884
885
886

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `With me.sbRows` ... `.Value = ActiveWindow.ScrollRow` in the form Initialize routine but there's no equivalent statement in the `sbRows_Change` routine.

The correct row gets stored in `mlPrevScrollRow` and that is used to update `ActiveWindow.ScrollRow`. The row number is never used to update `sbRows.Value` and thus it gets out of sync with the actual scroll row

Comment: Brilliant!! It would have taken me a long time to figure that out.  I added this line to the change routine:  

    Me.sbRows.Value = mlPrevScrollRow